# Managing Drupal Core in Git for Aegir Platforms

Tags: version-control, aegir, 7

We've started developing a platform to deploy sites with using Drupal 7.2. The platform is managed in git. However, as we do not touch core, what is the best place to managed core?

Should core also be in git on its own repo? Or should the dev team update core as they develop the platforms, and push core with the platform?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you also using [Drush Make](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make)? There is a 'classic' blog post about aegir and drush make at http://mig5.net/content/drupal-deployments-workflows-version-control-drushmake-and-aegir, and a lot has been written about it since then.

Comment: @marcvangend: Thank you for that link, I will have to examine drush make some more. So does this mean that for every time there is a update to the platform, it is pulled from git as a new platform? And site is then migrated to it? And after a while, the old platform can be deleted?

Comment: I must admit that I'm also in the process of figuring out my ideal workflow, but yes, as far as I currently understand, that is the idea.

Comment: Mm ... seems like that would get messy with several builds of platforms, especially when you have to migrate say 50+ sites ... no ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're now looking at a "[git branching model that works](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)" , and "[Drupal deployments & workflows with version control, drush_make, and Aegir](http://mig5.net/content/drupal-deployments-workflows-version-control-drushmake-and-aegir)"

Answer (score 4):

Our current (simplified) practice at work:

- Pull down the drupal core git repo http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/
- Add upstream to your local project that tracks the above repo
- When a new version of drupal is released, fetch the drupal repo and merge the appropriate tag

e.g.

```
cd /var/www/your-platform/
git fetch upstream
git merge 7.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can automate away a lot of the pain of the 'migrate to new platform' model in Aegir ( see http://mig5.net/node/342 ).

And you can batch-migrate sites from the frontend by using the 'Migrate' task in the *platform* (not site) node to also speed things up from the frontend if your sites all sharing the one platform.

Yes, old platforms can accumulate with no sites on them. However these can be deleted with the 'Delete' task in the frontend, and I hope to expand on automating that from the CLI too soon.